# Parsing and Normalizing file utilizing cmd's "for /f"

Tags: windows, batch-file, active-directory, cmd

I am working on building a batch file that queries AD, pipes the results into a .txt file, and then uses a for /f loop to parse and normalize the .txt file. I am running into some complications and would like to have other eyes take a look at it.

Also, would it be better to use a VBS to parse/normalize instead of an unwieldy for /f?

Batch:

```
@echo off
echo **********************************************
echo * This batch file will query members of a DL *
echo **********************************************
echo.   
set /p gn=Enter DL to get Members:

echo. 
CHOICE /C:12 /M "Choose 1 for DOMAIN1 query, Choose 2 for DOMAIN2 query."
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Label2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Label1 

:Label1
dsquery group DC=DOMAIN1,DC=NET -name "%gn%" | dsget group -members -expand >> "%gn%"List.txt
set fn = "%gn%"List.txt"
GOTO End

:Label2
dsquery group DC=DOMAIN2,DC=NET -name "%gn%" | dsget group -members -expand >> "%gn%"List.txt
set fn = "%gn%"List.txt"
GOTO End

:End

for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %i in ('more %fn%') do @ echo %i
```

Here are a few sample lines from the created .txt file:

```
"CN=LastName1\, FirstName1,OU=OU1,OU=OUSUB1,DC=DOMAIN1,DC=net"
"CN=LongLastName1\, LongFirstName1,OU=OU1,OU=OUSUB1,DC=DOMAIN1,DC=net"
"CN=LastName2, FirstName2,OU=OU1,OU=OUSUB1,DC=DOMAIN1,DC=net"
```

In the for loop, I am delimiting on commas.  From my sample lines, I am intending to store token 1 as "CN=LastName1\ and token 2 as  FirstName1 and go from there, but this is where I am stuck. My for loop is erroring with "fni was unexpected at this time" .  Is this something to do with escaping the %fn% variable from the single quotes in

```
('more %fn%')
```

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you use `in (%fn%)` instead of `in ('more %fn%')`? Note that if %fn% could contain spaces then you need to use the usebackq option and `in ("%fn%")`.

Comment: Note that `%i` doesn't work in batch scripts. You have to use `%%i`.

Answer (score 4):

Your assignment of `fn` is wrong. The spaces are significant. You are creating a variable with a space in the name. Also, your quotes are unbalanced which would cause parsing problems later on. The assignment occurs in two places. A correct form would look like:

```
set "fn=%gn%List.txt"
```

Note that the enclosing quotes are not included in the value when using this form with a quote before the variable name.

You must double the percents in a FOR /F statement when run within a batch file. Also, since I removed the quotes, you should add them in your MORE target. Finally, the @ is not needed since you turned ECHO OFF at the top of the script.

```
for /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%i in ('more "%fn%"') do echo %%i
```

Comment: Thanks! This helping me figure it the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Working Solution (with a bit of refactoring):

```
set /p gn=Enter DL to get Members:

IF EXIST "%gn%"-List.txt (
     DEL "%gn%"-List.txt
)

echo. 
CHOICE /C:12 /M "Type 1 to query DOMAIN1. Type 2 to query DOMAIN2."
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO Label2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Label1 


:Label1
dsquery group DC=DOMAIN1,DC=NET -name "%gn%" | dsget group -members -expand >>
"%gn%".txt
GOTO End

:Label2
dsquery group DC=DOMAIN2,DC=NET -name "%gn%" | dsget group -members -expand >>
"%gn%".txt
GOTO End

:End
REM Cleaning up the output -
SET "fn=%gn%.txt"
FOR /f "delims=, tokens=1,2" %%i in ('type "%fn%"') do ( 
     FOR /f "delims==\, tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%%i%%j") do (echo %%c,%%j) >>
"%gn%"-List.txt)

REM Deleting the Temp file -
DEL "%gn%".txt
echo.
echo %gn%-List.txt created!
PING 1.1.1.1 -n 4 >NUL
```